# Trying to install Bimp for Gimp on xubuntu: Makefile:9: recipe for target 'make' failed

Tags: software-installation, make, gimp

I am trying to install BIMP for GIMP 2.8

I'm on xubuntu.

Following help below I installed the recommended way by cloning from git.

I still get the makefile error and there is still no Batch option when I look in the menu under File in GIMP.

```
talyadavies@talyadavies-E201NAS:~/Documents/bimp$ cd
talyadavies@talyadavies-E201NAS:~$ git clone https://github.com/alessandrofrancesconi/gimp-plugin-bimp
Cloning into 'gimp-plugin-bimp'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1667, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (130/130), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
remote: Total 1667 (delta 70), reused 111 (delta 66), pack-reused 1537
Receiving objects: 100% (1667/1667), 2.89 MiB | 6.89 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (981/981), done.
talyadavies@talyadavies-E201NAS:~$ cd gimp-plugin-bimp
talyadavies@talyadavies-E201NAS:~/gimp-plugin-bimp$ make && make install
which gimptool-2.0 && \
gcc -o ./bin/bimp -O2 -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gimp-2.0 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-pointer-sign -DGIMP_DISABLE_DEPRECATED src/*.c src/manipulation-gui/*.c src/images/*.c -lgimpui-2.0 -lgimpwidgets-2.0 -lgimpmodule-2.0 -lgimp-2.0 -lgimpmath-2.0 -lgimpconfig-2.0 -lgimpcolor-2.0 -lgimpbase-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lm
/usr/bin/gimptool-2.0
src/bimp-manipulations-gui.c: In function ‘bimp_open_editwindow’:
src/bimp-manipulations-gui.c:48:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         save = &bimp_resize_save;
              ^
src/bimp-manipulations-gui.c:52:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         save = &bimp_crop_save;
              ^
src/bimp-manipulations-gui.c:56:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         save = &bimp_fliprotate_save;
              ^
src/bimp-manipulations-gui.c:60:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         save = &bimp_color_save;
              ^
src/bimp-manipulations-gui.c:64:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         save = &bimp_sharpblur_save;
              ^
src/bimp-manipulations-gui.c:68:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         save = &bimp_changeformat_save;
              ^
src/bimp-manipulations-gui.c:72:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         save = &bimp_watermark_save;
              ^
src/bimp-manipulations-gui.c:76:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         save = &bimp_rename_save;
              ^
src/bimp-manipulations-gui.c:80:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         save = &bimp_userdef_save;
              ^
src/bimp-operate.c: In function ‘apply_resize’:
src/bimp-operate.c:517:13: error: ‘GIMP_LAYER_MODE_NORMAL_LEGACY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
             GIMP_LAYER_MODE_NORMAL_LEGACY
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/bimp-operate.c:517:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
src/bimp-operate.c:535:37: error: ‘GIMP_FILL_BACKGROUND’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘GIMP_OFFSET_BACKGROUND’?
         gimp_drawable_fill(layerId, GIMP_FILL_BACKGROUND);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     GIMP_OFFSET_BACKGROUND
src/bimp-operate.c:539:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gimp_item_transform_translate’; did you mean ‘gimp_item_transform_rotate’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         gimp_item_transform_translate(layerId, -abs(view_w - final_w) / 2, -abs(view_h - final_h) / 2);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         gimp_item_transform_rotate
src/bimp-operate.c: In function ‘apply_color’:
src/bimp-operate.c:668:23: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gimp_drawable_brightness_contrast’; did you mean ‘gimp_brightness_contrast’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             success = gimp_drawable_brightness_contrast(
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       gimp_brightness_contrast
src/bimp-operate.c:685:23: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gimp_drawable_levels_stretch’; did you mean ‘gimp_levels_stretch’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             success = gimp_drawable_levels_stretch(out->drawable_ids[i]);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       gimp_levels_stretch
src/bimp-operate.c:711:31: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gimp_drawable_curves_spline’; did you mean ‘gimp_drawable_set_pixel’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                     success = gimp_drawable_curves_spline(out->drawable_ids[i], GIMP_HISTOGRAM_VALUE, colorcurve_num_points_v, colorcurve_ctr_points_v);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                               gimp_drawable_set_pixel
src/bimp-operate.c: In function ‘image_save’:
src/bimp-operate.c:1115:17: error: ‘GIMP_CONVERT_DITHER_FS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘GIMP_FIXED_DITHER’?
                 GIMP_CONVERT_DITHER_FS,
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 GIMP_FIXED_DITHER
src/bimp-operate.c:1116:17: error: ‘GIMP_CONVERT_PALETTE_GENERATE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘GIMP_TYPE_CONVERT_PALETTE_TYPE’?
                 GIMP_CONVERT_PALETTE_GENERATE,
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 GIMP_TYPE_CONVERT_PALETTE_TYPE
src/bimp-operate.c: In function ‘image_save_gif’:
src/bimp-operate.c:1192:9: error: ‘GIMP_CONVERT_DITHER_FS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘GIMP_FIXED_DITHER’?
         GIMP_CONVERT_DITHER_FS,
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         GIMP_FIXED_DITHER
src/bimp-operate.c:1193:9: error: ‘GIMP_CONVERT_PALETTE_GENERATE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘GIMP_TYPE_CONVERT_PALETTE_TYPE’?
         GIMP_CONVERT_PALETTE_GENERATE,
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         GIMP_TYPE_CONVERT_PALETTE_TYPE
src/bimp-operate.c: In function ‘image_save_avif’:
src/bimp-operate.c:1409:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
src/bimp-utils.c: In function ‘get_bimp_localedir’:
src/bimp-utils.c:172:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘readlink’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     readlink("/proc/self/exe", path, bufsize);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'make' failed
make: *** [make] Error 1
```

I have done sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev libgegl-dev

so I have the dependencies.

Comment: The gimp plugin bimp should not be related to grub

Comment: Shall I edit my question to remove references to grub?

Comment: Yes, and can you ask a different question about grub? When you ask that question, mention which all dependencies you had manually installed

Comment: You might be missing 2 dependencies of `libgimp2.0-dev` and `libpcre3-dev`.  `sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev libpcre3-dev` should take care of that.

Comment: libgimp2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.8.22-1).
libpcre3-dev is already the newest version (2:8.39-9ubuntu0.1).

Comment: *"I put the extracted files into a folder in Documents called bimp"* what extracted files, exactly? from where and how did you obtain the source code? It looks like the recommended way is to clone the [gimp-plugin-bimp github repository](https://github.com/alessandrofrancesconi/gimp-plugin-bimp)

Comment: Is there at least a `src` subdirectory with `.c` files in it?

Comment: I don't know how to clone the repository so I used the zip file from github and extracted it. There is a src folder but I can see nothing in it at all, even when I tick "Show hidden files."

Comment: To clone that git repo, just run `git clone https://github.com/alessandrofrancesconi/gimp-plugin-bimp` from a command line once you have `git` installed.

Comment: Should I clone it into the .gimp-2.8 folder? Or any folder?

Comment: Any folder is fine.  It will create `gimp-plugin-bimp` on its own.

Comment: Thanks. I have amended my question. Cloned from git and did make again. Same error.

Comment: Hmmmm, I had no issues installing that on Xubuntu 22.04 from the git version of it.  Do you have the `build-essential` package installed?  `sudo apt install build-essential`  After that, I am out of ideas for you other than going through a full maintenance check like running `fsck` on your drive from Live media to check for any errors, or the full `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, just shy of doing a Xubuntu reinstall.  Also making sure that you are running a supported version of Xubuntu, i.e. 20.04 LTS, 22.04 LTS, 23.04

Comment: I just read this   "Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install."  ...thanks for your help, I do have build-essential but I'm running 18.04.01 so maybe that's it.

Comment: 18.04 goes completely EOSS at the end of this month.  I definitely recommend an upgrade from 18.04.